# kendo angular dropdownlist undefined value with routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have an issue with Kendo Angular and routing.

The following dropdownlist is placed on the page.

The first time the widget is loaded a value is assigned to vm.xxx. This value is reflected in the kendo dropdownlist and the required validation doesn't go off (because a value is filled in). If i navigate to another route and come back to do the exact same logic an issue happens. The vm.xxx becomes undefined. I never set this manually to undefined. If I assign the value by calling window.setTimeout(function(){ vm.xxx = data.xxx; } then it works (but I want to avoid that).

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? I'm sure the kendo angular widgets should work in routing context.

Comment: This is the html: 
<select id="xxx" name="xxx" kendo-drop-down-list ng-model="vm.xxx" required k-data-text-field="'Text'" k-data-value-field="'Value'" k-data-source="vm.xxxResultSet" ng-disabled="vm.options.isReadonly" k-option-label="'Make a selection...'"></select>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the k-ng-delay attribute pointing to the same array :)

... k-data-source="vm.xxxSet" k-ng-delay="vm.xxxSet" ...